# Does golang's generic help reduce redundant codes using interfaces to implement interfaces?

Tags: go, generics

The following code is used to implement the `String()` and `Json` interfaces for many types. Notice that, in fact, as long as you implement a `LabelSet()` interface, you can implement the `String()` and `Json` interfaces.

And notice that the `WeekDay` and `Month` interfaces of the same name actually implement exactly the same logic.

However, whenever a new type, such as `Season`, is needed, you still have to make a copy of the `String()` and `Json` code to implement the `String` and `Json` interfaces for `Season`.

Is there a way to get generic to do this?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Labelable interface {
    LabelSet() []string
}

type WeekDay int

func (wd WeekDay) LabelSet() []string {
    return []string{
        "Mondy", "Tuesday", "Wednesday ",
    }
}

func (wd WeekDay) String() string {
    return wd.LabelSet()[int(wd)]
}

func (wd WeekDay) MarshalJSON() (data []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(wd.LabelSet()[int(wd)]), nil
}

type Month int

func (mon Month) LabelSet() []string {
    return []string{
        "January", "February", "March",
    }
}

func (mon Month) String() string {
    return mon.LabelSet()[int(mon)]
}

func (mon Month) MarshalJSON() (data []byte, err error) {
    return []byte(mon.LabelSet()[int(mon)]), nil
}

func main() {
    wd := WeekDay(0)
    mon := Month(1)
    fmt.Printf("wd=%s(%d)\n", wd.String(), wd)
    fmt.Printf("mon=%s(%d)\n", mon.String(), wd)
}
```

Comment: You must add methods to new types (unless they are structs and you embed something). The implementations may however be moved to utility functions. Also note that your JSON marshaling logic is flawed, you don't quote the string nor you escape special JSON chars. Best to leave that to the std lib, e.g. `return json.Marshal(someStringValue)`

Comment: thanks @icza , I thought generics introduced in go v1.18 can be helpful to this scenario. so called Marshal interface is just taken as an example to explain my quest..

Answer (score -1):

Here is one way using Type Parameters:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type JSONLabel[S fmt.Stringer] struct {
    Value S
}

func MakeJSONLabel[S fmt.Stringer](v S) JSONLabel[S] {
    return JSONLabel[S]{Value: v}
}

func (l JSONLabel[S]) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(l.Value.String())
}

func main() {
    type enc struct {
        Day    JSONLabel[time.Weekday]
        Month  JSONLabel[time.Month]
        Season JSONLabel[Season]
    }

    buf, _ := json.Marshal(&enc{
        Day:    MakeJSONLabel(time.Monday),
        Month:  MakeJSONLabel(time.March),
        Season: MakeJSONLabel(Autumn),
    })

    fmt.Println(string(buf))
    // Output:
    // {"Day":"Monday","Month":"March","Season":"Autumn"}
}
```

You could use this with the `Labelable` interface, but `fmt.Stringer` is more common, simpler, and provides the necessary functionality (eg, `time.Weekday` and `time.Month` above).

The example below shows 2 options for creating the `Season` enumeration used above:

1. Using `golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer` to automatically generate the `String` method via `go generate`, or
2. A simple reusuable `nameLookup` helper function.

```golang
// Fetch stringer via: go install golang.org/x/tools/cmd/stringer@latest
//
//go:generate stringer -type=Season

package main

type Season int

const (
    Summer Season = iota
    Autumn
    Winter
    Spring
)

/* Alternate, without stringer:
var seasons = []string{"Summer", "Autumn", "Winter", "Spring"}

func (s Season) String() string {
    return nameLookup("Season", seasons, int(s))
}

func nameLookup(typ string, names []string, n int) string {
    if n < 0 || len(names) <= n {
        return fmt.Sprintf("%s(%d)", typ, n)
    }
    return names[n]
}
*/
```

That said, you can get the JSON marshalling behaviour requested without Type Parameters by adding a trivial 3 line method to your types:

```golang
func (s Season) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(s.String())
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. In fact, the json interface is just an example for me, I intended to implement a template based class so that I don't have to manually implement one of its interfaces for all classes (Weekday, Month). Even if there is only one line of code to implement it, I think it is redundant.